# Make react-contexify contextmenu render on top of subsequent position:absolute items

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, contextmenu

So I have a page set up with nested [react-collapse-pane](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-collapse-pane). It basically uses `position: relative` and `absolute` to divide the page up into chunks like this (actual DOM is a bit more complicated as there are wrappers for subPanes and dividers):

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="verticalPane1">
        <div class="subPane1"></div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="subPane2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="verticalPane2">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have a custom context menu for each one of these panes. I was using a library [react-contexify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contexify)@V4. This library appends a `position:fixed` context menu to the end of the DOM, no matter where the React Component is placed:

Let's say I open the context menu for `subPane1`, the document becomes:

```
//Simplified body
<SplitPane direction="vertical">
    <SplitPane className="verticalPanel2" direction="horizontal">
        <Child className="subPanel1"/>
        <Child className="subPanel1"/>
    </SplitPane>
    <Child className="verticalPanel2"/>
</SplitPane>

//Child component
const Child = (props) => {
    ...//
    return <div className={props.className}>
        {showContextMenu && <ContextMenu />} 
    </div>
    //notice that the context menu's here but gets appended to the end of the DOM anyways. 
    //There are a lot of child-specific logic that I don't want to lift up; and accessing child functions from the parent is anti-pattern
}

//generated html
<div class="body">
    <div class="verticalPane1">
        <div class="subPane1"></div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="subPane2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="verticalPane2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contextMenu"></div> //context menu at the end of the DOM
```

So the context menu displays over everything nicely.

However V4 is filled with subtle bugs so I was trying out V5. V5 fixed all the subtle bugs I encountered, however, the library also decided to change to append the context menu to where is literally placed in the document (I think). So the example above became:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="verticalPane1">
        <div class="subPane1">
            <div class="contextMenu" /> //context menu moved to here. but still position: fixed
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="subPane2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="verticalPane2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Due to the HTML stacking logic, the context menu for `subPanel1` (and 2) renders underneath the absolutely positioned `verticalPane2`. `z-index` didn't fix it.

I'm trying to avoid rewriting the components and lift the context menu to the parent. That would require a significant amount of refactoring.

I would look for recommendations for other context menu libraries, except I'm afraid of encountering all the subtle bugs in react-contexify@V4. V5 fixed everything except for this one issue. [react-contextmenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contextmenu) looks like a decent one but it's not maintained at this point of time so I have my concerns (It's not like react-contexify's author responded to my github issue anyways lmao...)

I know I might have to fork the repo to have the context menu attach to the end of the DOM again, but I'm really hoping there's a less-hassle way of keeping the context menu always on top. css or maybe some light code.

Answer (score 2):

So figured it out with [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)
The official documentation provides a good enough example. So I just wrote a new `Portal` component and wrapped the context menu in it.